# Why does .hide() not work on elements within an jquery ui accordion?

Tags: jquery-ui, hide, accordion

Why does .hide() not work on elements within an jquery ui accordion? It does work before the call to `$("#accordion").accordion()`, but not afterwards. The .show() method works fine before and after. The .toggle() method works half (only the show part).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
                //$("#inside").hide("fade"); /* <-- this does work */
                $("#accordion").accordion();
                $("#inside").hide("fade"); /* <-- but this doesn't */
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
            <h3>Page 1</h3>
            <div id="page1">Blah</div>
            <h3>Page 2</h3>
            <div id="page2">
                <div id="inside">Blah too</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please explain not only how to solve it in another way, but more importantly why it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that calling `hide()` without the `"fade"` parameter, actually works (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WDXhg/6/)), I would say it has to do with the way that fade is implemented. The fade effect might be depending on the fact that the element is visible, since when you use `hide("fade")` when the div is showing it works (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WDXhg/4/)).

Comment: Seems I didn't test thoroughly enough, I didn't even think to try removing the transition.

Comment: Thanks Juan, the "fade" is indeed what is not working, not the hide() itself. I don't need the fade transition anyway especially because it is hidden in my application when it must be shown or hidden.

Answer (score 0):

<s>This happens because of `accordion`'s use of `hide`. The first time a panel is shown, the contents are shown as well, even if they were previously hidden, so if the panel is not open when you hide the contents, they will appear when you first select that panel.</s> See juan.facorro's explanation as it provides a correct explanation as to what's not working.

Here's one possible start of a workaround by showing the panel containing `#inside` initially, hiding it, then showing the first panel instead: http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/KuJJm/2/